# Compile time counting/numbering of template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor

For a low level application, I define sort of an index as a type at compile time:

```
template <int IDX_, class T_>
class Idx{
  using TYPE = T_;
  static const int IDX = IDX_;
}
```

Usage is then:

```
using region1_field1 = Idx<0, double>;
using region1_field2 = Idx<1, double>;
using region1_field3 = Idx<2, float>;

using region2_field1 = Idx<0, char>;
using region2_field2 = Idx<1, char>;
```

This `Idx` template basically does a good job for me, but it's annoying and a bit dangerous that you have to set the `IDX_` parameter manually. **Is there a way to automatically count and set that parameter at compile time?** As you see, I would need multiple instances of that counter for `region1_*` and `region2_*`.

Finally, the class is used for something like:

```
template <class IDX_>
typename IDX_::TYPE getValue(IDX_ idx, int pos){
  return (reinterpret_cast<typename IDX_::TYPE*>(data_ptrs[IDX_]))[pos];
}
```

Comment: Do you want the index to be part of the type (which it is now due to your use of it as a template argument), or do you just want the `IDX` member to be autoincreasing?

Comment: What is the significance of second parameter `T_`? Can it be fixed to appropriate type, say `std::size_t`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: It would be fine if it is autoincreasing and remain static and const.

Comment: @Nawaz: `Idx` is used to index into a byte field. `T_` contains the information about what type of data is in that field.

Comment: what do you do with `region1_field1` etc.? where is the index->type mapping coming from?

Comment: The patten of the constants `0,1,2` and then `0,1` is not consistent. When to increase it, and when to start it from zero again? How to decide this?

Comment: Why not `region1_field<2>`?

Comment: I edited the question to show usage of the index. And, as I mentioned, I would maybe need multiple of this counters.

Comment: If I got your point, you would have a template class counting the number of its own instantiations. If so, you may want to simplify your question to make your need explicit. I have no answer, but I'm afraid this will not be possible.

Comment: Just complement the IDX in the constructor ,but then you will have to remove the const keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that you are looking for [`boost::mpl::vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/vector.html).

So I'd do this (take into account that I only try to imagine your use case):

Necessary `boost::mpl`:

```
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/pair.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
```

So you can have your "regions":

```
using region1 = boost::mpl::vector<double, double, float>;
using region2 = boost::mpl::vector<char, char>;
```

And `Idx` class to have `Idx<region1,1>` shortcut:

```
template <typename Region, int Pos>
using Idx = boost::mpl::pair<Region,boost::mpl::int_<Pos>>;
```

And access to `Idx` type:

```
template <typename Idx>
using IdxType = typename boost::mpl::at<typename Idx::first, typename Idx::second>;
```

Now - how it works:

I imagine your dataptrs as something like this (simplified version;):

```
struct DataPtrs
{
    char data[20]= "Hello from MPL";
    template <typename Idx>
    void* operator[](Idx idx)
    {
        return data;
    }
};

DataPtrs data_ptrs;
```

And the access to it - will look in this way:

```
template <class Idx>
typename IdxType<Idx>::type getValue(int pos)  {
    return reinterpret_cast<typename IdxType<Idx>::type*>(data_ptrs[Idx()])[pos];
}
```

And `main`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using region2_0 = Idx<region2,0>;
    std::cout << getValue<region2_0>(1);
}
```

So - my advice - use `boost::mpl` - or copy from it necessary parts if you cannot use boost in your project. Of course you must align my proposal to your needs...

At the end - you can try it all at [ideone](http://ideone.com/D0PTAG)

Answer (score 1):

Make your tags `struct foo {};` empty.

Store them in `template<class...>struct types{};` a type list.

Store that in a `template<class Names, class T>struct field{};` typed field thing.

Get value searches for the tag in the Names type list in the field in question.

Invariants, like each tag occurs once, and that each used tag in a lookup is used in the Names, can be compile time checked.

You could even make a collection of fields with buffer position info, to allow get value to find the buffer from the tag without being told, and cross-field tag uniqueness enforced.